# Power Series Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, initial-value-problems

> Consider the initial value problem
>   $$xu''+\sin(x)u=0 \ \ \ \ u(0)=0, u'(0)=2$$
>   Derive the first $4$ non-zero terms of a power series solution to this problem about the point $x=0$.

I know the solution will have the from $$u(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_kx^k$$
But upon differentiating, I get that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k(k-1)A_kx^{k-2}+\sin(x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_kx^{k-1}=0$$
and do not know how to proceed. Would an initial substitution help?

Comment: You need to write $\sin(x)$ as a power series as well.

Comment: So $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k(k-1)A_kx^{k-2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}A_kx^{3k}=0?$$

Comment: No, the second summand needs to be a product : $\displaystyle\sum{\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k}}\times \sum{A_k}x^{k-1}$. You then need to expand that(not all of it just the powers you need).

Answer (score 1):

I willshow you how to proceed following daruma's comment. Let
$$
u=2\,x +A_2\,x^2+A_3\,x^3+\dots
$$
Then
$$
x\,u''=2\,A_2\,x+6\,A_3\,x^2+\dots
$$
and
\begin{align}
(\sin x)u&=\Bigl(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\dots\Bigr)\bigl(2\,x +A_2\,x^2+A_3\,x^3+\dots\bigr)\\
&=2\,x^2+A_2\,x^3+\Bigl(A_3-\frac13\Bigr)\,x^4+\dots
\end{align}
Now sum the series for $x\,u''$ and $(\sin x)u$, set it equal to $0$ and obtain equations for the coefficients $A_n$, $n\ge2$.

Comment: there is a typo with your expansion of $\sin(x)$

Comment: @Bell Thanks for come ting. I have edited.