# Convergence of the Power Series for $xu''+\sin(x)u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Consider the initial value problem
>   $$xu''+\sin(x)u=0 \ \ \ \ u(0)=0, u'(0)=2$$
>   What can be said about the radius of convergence of this series?

I have determined that the first four nonzero terms (about the point $x=0$) of the power series are $$2x,-x^2,\frac{1}{6}x^3,-\frac{1}{72}x^4$$
How can I test for convergence? Intuitively it looks not to converge, but how can I  show this?

**edit**

The solution will have the from $$u(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_kx^k.$$
Differentiating,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} k(k-1)A_kx^{k-1}+\sin(x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_kx^k&=0 \\
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} k(k-1)A_kx^{k-1}+\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}A_kx^k&=0 \\
(2A_2x+6A_3x^2+12A_4x^3+20A_5x^4+30A_6x^5+42A_7x^6+..)+\left(2x^2+A_2x^3+\left(A_3-\frac{1}{3}\right)x^4+\left(A_4-\frac{A_2}{6!}\right)x^5+\left(A_5-\frac{A_3}{3!}+\frac{2}{5!}\right)x^6+..\right)=0
\end{align}
Equating coefficients, $x^{2k}=0$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.
$$6A_3+2=0\implies A_3=-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$20A_5+A_3-\frac{1}{3}=0\implies A_5=\frac{1}{30}$$
$$42A_7+A_5-\frac{A_3}{3!}+\frac{2}{5!}=0\implies A_7=-\frac{19}{7560}$$
Hence $$u=2x-\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{30}x^5-\frac{19}{7560}x^7+..$$

Comment: I have include how I obtained the series. Finding this series was related to my last post. Not sure where I have gone wrong. I took the advice from the last post and thought I had produced the correct solution.

Comment: If $u=2x+A_2 x^2+A_3 x^3+A_4x^4+\dots,$ then $\sin(x)u =2x^2+ A_2x^3+(A_3-1/3)x^4+(A_4-A_2/6)x^5+\dots.$

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I was just following the solution provided on this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2886714/557493

Comment: I think I have found this mistake in that post btw. The answer provided to the OP (me) mistypes the power series expansion for $\sin(x)$.

Comment: @Somos is the coefficient of $x^7$ suppose to be $\frac{-19}{7560}$? I obtained this as I thought $A_7=\frac{1}{42}\left(\frac{A_3}{6}-A_5-\frac{2}{120}\right)$.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [MSE question 2886608](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2886608) by the same user.

Comment: Should I delete that post? The information provided was incorrect anyway. This question was for convergence as well.

Comment: Yes, of course. no sense in having duplicate questions.

Comment: I have voted to close that page, could you please do the same. I can't delete it as "other have invested time in answering this question".  Also, was I correct with the coefficient of $x^7$?

Comment: Edit the question and show **al**l of your work so far.

Comment: I have done this.

Comment: The problem is with solving for $A_5 = 1/30$. You have $-1/30$ which is a sign error. The next $A_7=-19/7560$ is correct. I have a typo in my 1st comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81902/discussion-between-somos-and-bell).